# How to downgrade version of sumo

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using instant veins with version 1.8.0 for Sumo. However, I want to use a veins project that was last tested on 0.30 version and I can't run the simulation without that version. How can I downgrade to that version of sumo?

More precisely, I am getting this error: TraCI server SUMO 1.8.0 reports API version 20, which is unsupported. We recommend using SUMO 0.30.0 in module

Comment: Go ask in directly in the repo

Comment: The repo is not active whatsoever. I am merely asking on how to downgrade my version of sumo.

Comment: Instant Veins 5.1-i2 ships with Veins 5.1, which should support SUMO 0.30. See [here](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.cc#L39) for a list of TraCI versions supported by Veins 5.1, see [here](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/v0_30_0/sumo/src/traci-server/TraCIConstants.h#L36) for the TraCI version used by SUMO 0.30.0.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found is to uninstall the current version of SUMO and install another one.

Are you working on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

If you can comment the lines which check for the sumo version in veins. But remember possibility of simulation crash can't be ruled out in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The build process of Instant Veins 5.1-i2 builds SUMO from source. You can find the steps it performs [listed in its repository](https://github.com/sommer/instant-veins/blob/instant-veins-5.1-i2/ansible/roles/sumo/tasks/main.yml), along with [the values it uses for variables therein](https://github.com/sommer/instant-veins/blob/instant-veins-5.1-i2/ansible/roles/sumo/defaults/main.yml).

Its a matter of personal preference if you want to

- follow these steps manually, but using a different number; or
- change the build variables and build a custom version of Instant Veins from this template; or
- install SUMO manually, following the [steps in its documentation](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Installing/Linux_Build.html).

In the end, all that Instant Veins 5.1-i2 assumes is that a manually-built version of SUMO can be found in `~/src/sumo` (by default, this is a symbolic link to `~/src/sumo-1.8.0`).